# How to include another xml file

Tags: code-generation, gsl-code-generator

This question is about gsl code generator: https://github.com/imatix/gsl

Let's say I have an xml file that contains all the "links" I want to include on my site:

```
<link icon="facebook" name="Facebook" url = "http://www.facebook.com/blah" />
<link icon="camera" name="Youtube" url = "http://www.youtube.com/user/blah" />
<link icon="film" name="Picasa" url = "http://picasaweb.google.com/323423" />
<link icon="twitter" name="Twiter" url = "http://twitter.com/blah" />
```

How can I load that file and render the links?

I tried the following in gsl script:

```
links = xml . load_file("links.xml")
```

and then this in my template:

```
.for site.link
        <li><i class="icon-$(link.icon)"></i>
        <a href="$(link.url)">$(link.name)</a>
.endfor
```

But the result is nothing.

My full source code for this is in a small repo:
https://bitbucket.org/drozdyuk/fruits-sample/src/07efb4910bde?at=master

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<links>
  <link .../>
  <link .../>
</links>
```

and then:

```
global.links = xml.load_file ("links.xml")
for links.link
   ....
endfor
```

Comment: Woot, that works! I also needed to place the `load_file("links.xml")` call before the `gsl from "template.gsl"`. Repo updated.

Comment: Great! The xml.load_file call returns an item, so you want to always use well-formed XML (with a single top level item). By loading into the global scope, you get multiple top-level items you can work with.